# Subshell result different than expected

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am setting up a list to delete old files and remain the latest 5 versions, where a file amount is deleted from the list.

GNU bash, v4.3.48

file: test

```
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-0b7c6c7f-17.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-0c77b6bf-15.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-191743df-10.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-2fa8b89d-14.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-4fdca5ca-18.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-5bd9abf4-7.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-6a6743ee-11.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-9d47b9a5-16.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-bc77eec4-19.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-cfd66059-12.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-d136baa3-13.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-ffa49b6b-9.tgz"
```

test subshell:

```
$ cat test | sed -r 's/.*-([0-9]+\.tgz).*/\1/g' | sort -n | tail -n 5 | xargs| sed 's/ /|/g;s/^/\"/g;s/$/\"/g'
```

results (files to keep):

```
"15.tgz|16.tgz|17.tgz|18.tgz|19.tgz"
```

command to ignore 5 files.

```
cat teste | grep -vE $(cat teste | sed -r 's/.*-([0-9]+\.tgz).*/\1/g' | sort -n | tail -n 5 | xargs| sed 's/ /|/g;s/^/\"/g;s/$/\"/g')
```

results (files to delete):

```
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-0c77b6bf-15.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-191743df-10.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-2fa8b89d-14.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-5bd9abf4-7.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-6a6743ee-11.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-cfd66059-12.tgz", 
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-d136baa3-13.tgz",
```

The `grep -vE` selects 15.tgz to delete. but I would like 15.tgz to be kept. Like 16.tgz, 17.tgz, 18.tgz and 19.tgz.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it in two passes, just a single is enough. You don't need "first extract the indexes to be keeped" and then "join the indexes to be keeped with the list of all indexes and remove the disjoint group". Do both at the same time just working on a stream as it passes.

The following script with comments in code:

```
cat <<EOF |
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-0b7c6c7f-17.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-0c77b6bf-15.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-191743df-10.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-2fa8b89d-14.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-4fdca5ca-18.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-5bd9abf4-7.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-6a6743ee-11.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-9d47b9a5-16.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-bc77eec4-19.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-cfd66059-12.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-d136baa3-13.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-ffa49b6b-9.tgz"
EOF
# extract the strings inside "
sed -r 's/[[:space:]]*"([^"]*).*/\1/' |
# sort using the numbers
# sort using `-` as the separator for fields and sort using 5th field
sort -t- -n -k5,5 |
# remove 5 newest files
head -n -5  |
# remove the rest of the files
xargs echo rm
```

outputs:

```
rm npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-5bd9abf4-7.tgz npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-ffa49b6b-9.tgz npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-191743df-10.tgz npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-6a6743ee-11.tgz npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-cfd66059-12.tgz npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-d136baa3-13.tgz npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-2fa8b89d-14.tgz
```

If you are not sure about the number `-` in the filenames, a better way would be to first extract the numbers in front of `[0-9]*.tgz` and place them on the file with the filename. Then sort the list and remove the indexes.

```
cat <<EOF |
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-0b7c6c7f-17.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-0c77b6bf-15.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-191743df-10.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-2fa8b89d-14.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-4fdca5ca-18.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-5bd9abf4-7.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-6a6743ee-11.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-9d47b9a5-16.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-bc77eec4-19.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-cfd66059-12.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-d136baa3-13.tgz",
        "npm/usagecontrol-ui/usagecontrol-ui-ffa49b6b-9.tgz"
EOF
# extract the strings inside "
sed -r 's/[[:space:]]*"([^"]*).*/\1/' |
# extract the index in front of .thz and put it in front of the line
sed -r 's/^.*-([0-9]*)\.tgz$/\1 &/' |
# sort using the extracted numbers
sort -n -k1,1 |
# remove the indexes
cut -d' ' -f2- |
# remove 5 newest files
head -n -5  
# remove the rest of the files
xargs echo rm
```

Notes:

- `s/ /|/g;s/^/\"/g;s/$/\"/g` -  Escaping doublequotes inside singlequotes does nothing. It's the same as `s/ /|/g;s/^/"/g;s/$/"/g`.
- `| xargs|` is useless, it's an empty operation. It is almost as equal to `| cat |`.